# How can I run multiple Stored Procedures Files & Triggers (.sql) From MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, xampp

I am trying to run a set of sql files with stored procedures and triggers in my windows XAMPP environment. Some suggested to me using a batch script but I do not know how to do this in windows.

Is it possible to run all these .sql files from within MySQL Workbench? How? If not, can anyone tell me how to run a batch file within windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Workbench doesn't support the command "SOURCE" so the next best thing is is (at least in windows) is to run a batch job. Simply create a new .sql file and add the full path to each .sql file like so:

**Create the batch file:**

In windows,  the batch file can be a .sql with the sql comman SOURCE which calls the other .sql files, like so:

create run.sql

```
SOURCE C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sql\procs\sp_article_delete.sql
SOURCE C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sql\procs\sp_article_insert.sql
SOURCE C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sql\procs\sp_article_load.sql
```

**Open Command Line and CD to MySQL Folder**

Open the command line, and cd to MySQL. If you are using XAMPP, the command/location should be something like:

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin\
```

Execute the Batch File by pressing ENTER

**Last, simply load mysql and run the batch file using the following command:**

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 my_database_name -vvv < C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sql\procs\run.sql
```

The execution above means the following:

```
mysql -u <username> -h <host> <database> -vvv < <batch_path_file_name>
```

-vvv shows all the queries being executed and the rows affected for debugging.

That's it. All .sql files mentioned in the run.sql file will be executed.